# Flutter show and hide AlertDialog depend on dynamic value

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, widget

In this snippet event value is stream value that can change dynamically.

```
LocationPermissions().serviceStatus.listen((event) {
    if(event == ServiceStatus.disabled){
      print('Location Disabled');
      testAlert(context); // Show dialog
    }else{
      testAlert(context); //I want hide dialog when user enable location.How do?
      print('Location Enabled');
         }
}
```

This is my dialog code.

```
void testAlert(BuildContext context){
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      // return object of type Dialog
      return AlertDialog(
        title: new Text("Location service disable"),
        content: new Text("You must enable your location access"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog
          new FlatButton(
            child: new Text("Go Setting"),
            onPressed: () {
              openLocationSetting();
              //visible ?Navigator.pop(context , true): Navigator.pop(context, false);

            },
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

How show and hide depend on event value.Thanks.

Comment: use `Navigator.pop(context)` to hide the dialog

Comment: where add?that code bro @Jide

Comment: I wrote an answer. check it

Answer (score 1):

When user has enabled `location` then do no call the dialog method , just remove this line `testAlert(context);`

```
LocationPermissions().serviceStatus.listen((event) {
    if(event == ServiceStatus.disabled){
      print('Location Disabled');
      testAlert(context); // Show dialog
    }else{
     // testAlert(context); //remove or just comment this line 
      print('Location Enabled');
         }
```

}

**Update**:-

> Dismiss alert on flat button by calling `Navigator.pop()` in this
> dialog will be dismissed

**Example**:-

```
void testAlert(BuildContext context){
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      // return object of type Dialog
      return AlertDialog(
        title: new Text("Location service disable"),
        content: new Text("You must enable your location access"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog
          new FlatButton(
            child: new Text("Go Setting"),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context)
              openLocationSetting();
              

            },
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Call this in lifecycle ie `didChangeAppLifecycleState()` method when user comes back to app again

```
@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
  // If user resumed to this app, check permission
  if(state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
   LocationPermissions().serviceStatus.listen((event) {
    if(event == ServiceStatus.disabled){
      print('Location Disabled');
      testAlert(context); // Show dialog
    }else{
      testAlert(context); //I want hide dialog when user enable location.How do?
      print('Location Enabled');
         }
    }  
  }
}
```

Comment: I did it sir.If i remove that line when user enable location service how detect dialog is show or not.

Comment: your answer mean when user click GoSetting button dialog will dismiss but user don't choose location on.I want to dismiss and show depend on asynchronous value

Comment: updated my answer, you need to check in resume lifecycle method when user comes back to app , check again if location is enabled or not , if not show dialog

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216485/discussion-between-h-zan-and-quick-learner).